# sending events with reminders through Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, reminder

There is no end to the uselessness of Microsoft Office.

Is there any way, at all, to send an event with reminders to others using Microsoft Outlook 2007?  I have tried creating a shared calender through Exchange Server, but reminders can not be shared this way to avoid people getting 'unnecessary notifications' (which is way worse than not getting one you needed, right?).

So I tried what they said here and inviting other people to an event with a notification shared:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy/thread/c7792790-7e9b-47a7-9e58-d746c11a2f58

Despite setting the reminder before sharing the event, guess what?  No notification.

Is this something completely impossible in Outlook without paying for addons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that what I was looking to do is completely impossible with Outlook native.  As in not even a hard-to-find, disabled-by-default, client-side option.

Go Microsoft!!!